# How to fix ajax call in firefox browser, But its working fine in chrome browser

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsp, firefox

Following is javascript, to call ajax function, $ajax is not working in firefox but it is working in chrome. ajax is not receiving response in firefox browser.

function ajaxAsyncRequest() {

```
            alert("ajaxAsyncRequest function");
            var tempValUrl = $(".urlVal").val();
            var url = tempValUrl + 'DepartmentUser/departmentUserTokenReceive';
            alert("url=="+url);

                $.ajax({
                        url : url,
                        method : 'GET',
                        contentType : "application/json",
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(response) {
                            alert(response);
                            var obj = response;
                            alert(obj);
                            alert("keyType" + obj.keyType);

                            if (obj.keyType == "sign") {
                                document.getElementById("signName").value = obj.name;
                                document.getElementById("certNumber").value = obj.serialNumber;
                                document.getElementById("signCa").value = obj.issuer;
                                document.getElementById("signExpiryDate").value = obj.tempDateTime;
                                document.getElementById("signPublicKey").value = obj.publicKey;
                            }

                            if (obj.keyType == "cipher") {
                                document.getElementById("cipherName").value = obj.name;
                                document.getElementById("cipherCertNumber").value = obj.serialNumber;
                                document.getElementById("cipherCa").value = obj.issuer;
                                document.getElementById("cipherExpiryDate").value = obj.tempDateTime;
                                document.getElementById("cipherPublicKey").value = obj.publicKey;
                            }

                        }

                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define event as parameter of the event handler :-

event.preventDefault();

Comment: I added event.preventDefault();. but its not working.